# Short story about a man who works and lives alone, who is repulsed by people when he has to leave his cubicle

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Read this story a long time back. It's about a man at the controls as he works; his basic needs are provided. Food, clothes, etc. are made available to him. One day he wakes up to find the system is not working. He comes out of his cubicle to find hundreds of others have also come out to see what is wrong. The touch of another human being repulses him.

Is this an Asimov or a Clarke? Came back to me during the pandemic when work from home began in real earnest.

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to SF&F!  Do you have any memory of when you read this, or where (anthology, magazine?), or when it might have been written (your mention of Asimov/Clarke is a bit of a hint, but anything you remember could help someone identify it).  What were the controls he was working?

Comment: http://www.visbox.com/prajlich/forster.html has some similarities.

Comment: Living/working alone and being revolted by other people is reminiscent of the Solarians from Asimov's *The Naked Sun*, to keep to the suggested authors.

Answer (score 22):

This may be E M Forster's [The Machine Stops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Machine_Stops)

**It's bout a man at the controls as he works; his basic needs are provided. Food, clothes, etc. are made available to him.**

> The story describes a world in which most of the human population has
> lost the ability to live on the surface of the Earth. Each individual
> now lives in isolation below ground in a standard room, with all
> bodily and spiritual needs met by the omnipotent, global Machine.
> Travel is permitted, but is unpopular and rarely necessary.
> Communication is made via a kind of instant messaging/video
> conferencing machine with which people conduct their only activity:
> the sharing of ideas and what passes for knowledge.

The story itself is [here](http://www.visbox.com/prajlich/forster.html) (thanks to @FuzzyBoots).

The main character is a woman (as pointed out in the comment by [@Clara Diaz Sanchez](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/125981/clara-diaz-sanchez))

**The touch of another human being repulses him.**

> People were almost exactly alike all over the world, but the
> attendant of the air-ship, perhaps owing to her exceptional duties,
> had grown a little out of the common. She had often to address
> passengers with direct speech, and this had given her a certain
> roughness and originality of manner. When Vashti swerved away from the
> sunbeams with a cry, she behaved barbarically - she put out her hand
> to steady her.
>
> "How dare you!" exclaimed the passenger. "You forget yourself!"
>
> The woman was confused, and apologized for not having let her fall.
> **People never touched one another. The custom had become obsolete,
> owing to the Machine.**

Comment: Isn't this the current reality?

Comment: Shh.  The Google AI might hear.

Comment: Isn't "The Machine Stops" about a woman, rather than a man?

Comment: I'm still stunned, that this was written in *1909*.

Comment: A non-mobile wikipedia link would be objectively better, but that's too small a change for me to suggest

Comment: I'm going to make some improvements later today - I'll change the link too

Comment: The main character is a woman, but a lot of the story is driven by her adult son.

Comment: Glad to be able to vote up as it is such an excellent story – and was the first thing to occur to me when I read the question.

Answer (score 9):

I think this might be ["Cocoon"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57896) by Keith Laumer (1948).

In "Cocoon" the protagonist lives in an entirely contained personal enclosure, as does everyone else in the city he inhabits. He sees via TV, whch offers such channels as Light and Deep Sitcom, Pubinf, Office, Therapy, and several others. He speaks via a throat microphone. The machinery delivers pre-digested food of various sorts. He has lived this way for many decades.

Problems seem to be developing with the services. Eventually the protagonist breaks free of his cocoon, to find that a small group is trying to rouse people to get out of the city before it is buried by a glacier.  But they say he is too old to come with them. He reaches the surface with a struggle, appreciates the view, and dies.

[image: Cover of The Best of Keith Laumer, illustrating "Cocoon"]

Cover of *The Best of Keith Laumer*, illustrating "Cocoon"